# Grouping text file in linux based on names

Tags: text, awk, terminal

Using linux without a great deal of experience in regex or awk and not sure what the best way to go about this is.

I have a text file that looks something like

```
492 "Steve Smith"
455 "Steve Smith"
322 "Steve Smith"
123 "John Doe"
234 "John Doe"
etc.
```

My desired output is:

```
Steve Smith - 492, 455, 322
John Doe - 123, 234
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gets what you want (but without the commas):

```
$ awk -F'"' '{a[$2]=a[$2]$1} END{for (name in a) printf "%s - %s\n",name,a[name]}' file
Steve Smith - 492 455 322 
John Doe - 123 234
```

To include the commas:

```
$ awk -F'"' '{a[$2]=a[$2]", "$1+0} END{for (name in a) printf "%s - %s\n",name,substr(a[name],3)}' file
Steve Smith - 492, 455, 322
John Doe - 123, 234
```

#### How it works

- `-F'"'`

  This tells awk to use a double-quote, `"`, as the field separator.  In this way the number is field 1 and the name is field 2.
- `a[$2]=a[$2]", "$1+0`

  For every line, we append  a comma and a number to the value of associative array `a` with key `$2`.

  The second field, `$2`, is the name.  `a[$2]` is the list of numbers for that name.  For each new line we read, we replace `a[$2]` with the prior value of `a[$2]`,  followed by comma-space, followed by the first field plus zero, `$1+0`.  We use the `+0` to force the first field to be a number.  That eliminates extra space in the first field.
- `END{for (name in a) printf "%s - %s\n",name,substr(a[name],3)}`

  After we have reached the end of the file, we print each name followed by a space-dash-space, followed by our list of numbers.  The `substr` function removes the superfluous comma from the beginning of the number string.

  The names are printed in arbitrary order.  You may want to pass the output through `sort` to put it in alphabetical order.

Comment: really appreciate the breakdown of each section

Answer (score 5):

You can import your file into a sqlite3 database, and make a select query.

```
$ sudo apt install sqlite3
$ sqlite3
> create table test (num integer, name  text);
> .separator " "
> .import your_file test
> select name || " - " || group_concat(num) from test group by name;
```

Comment: If you use [q](http://harelba.github.io/q/) you don't even need to do the steps, just `q "select c2 || ' - ' || group_concat(c1)  from test.txt group by c2"`

Comment: This is a really interesting solution that I wouldn't have thought of, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

***Solution 1st:***

```
awk '{
match($0,/".*"/);
val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
a[val]=a[val]?a[val] OFS $1:$1
}
END{
for(i in a){
 print i" - "a[i]
}}
' OFS=", "   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
"John Doe" - 123, 234
"Steve Smith" - 492, 455, 322
```

***Solution 2nd:*** In case you want to have output in same sequence as per your Input_file then following could help you in same too.

```
awk '{
match($0,/".*"/);
val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
}
!b[val]++{
  num++
}
{
a[val]=a[val]?a[val] OFS $1:$1;
c[num]=a[val];
d[num]=val
}
END{
for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
  print d[i]" - "c[i]
}}
' OFS=", "   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
"Steve Smith" - 492, 455, 322
"John Doe" - 123, 234
```

***Explanation of solution 1st:***

```
awk '{
match($0,/".*"/);              ##match is awk out of the box function which will match a regex provided by us into a variable or current line, I am matching here everything that starts from " to till " in current line.
val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); ##creating variable named val here whose value will be substring(substr is awk out of the box keyword) this substring starting point will be value of RSTART variable till the value of RLENGTH variable. NOTE: RSTART and RLENGTH variables values will be SET once a match is found in match function which we used previous step.
a[val]=a[val]?a[val] OFS $1:$1 ##creating array a whose index is variable val and it is concatenating its value in it as per the index of array.
}
END{                           ##starting end section of awk here which will be executed once complete Input_file is read.
for(i in a){                   ##starting a for loop here which will iterate in array a all values.
 print i" - "a[i]              ##printing the value of variable named i(which is actually index of array a) then " - " and then value of array a whose index is i.
}}
' OFS=", "  Input_file         ##Setting OFS(output field separator) value as ", " and mentioning Input_file name here too.
```